# How do I generate a verifier with tweepy to allow other people to authorize my twitter app?

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, tweepy, twitter-oauth

I am trying to make a simple app that will allow users to authenticate the app through their twitter account, which will maintain a list of followers and blocked accounts, updating the accounts which authorize it every so often. What I am struggling with is generating the verifier for the user when they click the link. Below is my code, mostly copied from the documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/authentication.html#legged-oauth) in the 3 legged OAuth section.

How do I get the verifier so I can store the user token and secret to open a client object with those credentials?

```
import tweepy
import JSONReader #Custom class to retrieve credentials easily without showing raw data

keys = JSONReader.get_client('credentials.json')

oauth_user_handler = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    keys[0], keys[1], # These are the client key/secret
    callback="https://127.0.0.1"
)

auth_url = oauth_user_handler.get_authorization_url(signin_with_twitter=True)

print(auth_url) 

access_token, access_token_secret = oauth_user_handler.get_access_token(verifier= IDK HOW TO GET THIS)

client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=keys[0],
    consumer_secret=keys[1],
    access_token=access_token,
    access_token_secret=access_token_secret
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The verifier token will be sent to your callback URL by Twitter.

Imagine that you have defined this callback URL (preferably in your app settings):

> callback_url = http://127.0.0.1/callback

Then, when the user will click on the authorize button, it will be redirected to:

> http://127.0.0.1/callback?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_verifier=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

Where the verifier is the YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY.

Comment: Ohh okay I can see that in the link now, how do I grab that value from the link in with tweepy after the user authenticates? Thank you!

Comment: @Nick5741 `parse_qs(urlparse(returned_url))` will give you a dict with all the query params.